# Orion CB saves device with 'entity_name' value in 'id' field

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm trying to develop IoTA with lazy attributes. And found that Context Broker saves device 'entity_name' field in 'id', so when CB makes request for lazy attributes, IoTA can't found device with such id.

With purpose to create device entity I make this request to IoTA:

```
'devices': [{
    'device_id': 'idSensor14',
    'entity_name': 'nameSensor14',
    'entity_type': 'anysensor',
    'attributes': [
        {
            'name': 't',
            'type': 'celsius'
        }
    ],
    'lazy': [
        {
            'name': 'b',
            'type': 'mybits'
        }
    ]                 
}]
```

Then if we request entitites list in CB ('v2/entities/') we discover:

```
{ "id":"nameSensor15",
    "type":"anysensor",
    "t":{"type":"celsius","value":"","metadata":{}}}
```

It seems that CB saves device with wrong id. This is request for lazy attributes:

```
data = {
    "entities": [{
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": myid,
        "type": entity_type
    },
    "attributes": ["b"]
]}
```

And this is error in IoA log:

*op=IoTAgentNGSI.ContextServer | srv=myhome | subsrv=/sensors | msg=Query error [DEVICE_NOT_FOUND] handling request: No device was found with id:nameSensor15*

If delete entity_name from registration request, then CB will use device id = 'anysensors:idSensor14'. My Orion version is 1.7.0, and iotagent-node-lib version is 2.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was in using upper case letters in fiware service name for device registration headers and iota config, so I should use `myhome` instead of `myHome`, for example. It's same for memory and mongo device registry types.

Answer (score 0):

IOTAgent should create the entity in the CB using `entity_name` as `id`. In your case, that means `nameSensor14`.

Maybe the `nameSensor15` you see corresponds to some other provisioning operation.

I'd recommend to do a clean test. I mean:

1. Stop all processes (both IOTA and CB).
2. Cleanup all the DBs (look for DBs starting with `orion` and `iot` in your Mongo shell)
3. Start CB
4. Start IOTAgent
5. Run the create device request
6. Before running any other request, check entities (`GET /v2/entities`) and registrations (`GET v1/registry/contextEntities/<entity_id>`) at CB in order to see that the entity was created with the proper id, along with the registration corresponding to the lazy attribute.

Comment: If CB saves `entity_name` in `id`, how in this case make request correctly for lazy attributes to CB? Because device in IoTA have other `id`, IoTA log shows `device not found` error on request to CB.

Comment: Not sure of getting your point... What IOTA does is *to map* the device in the southbound interface (identified by `device_id`) to an entity in the ContextBroker at northbound interface, using such entity an `id` (in the NGSIv2 API offered by the CB) which is set to `entity_name`. The IOTA knows the reverse mapping when time of resolving forwarding queries corresponding to lazy attributes comes.  Hoping this information clarifies how all the pieces work together :)

Comment: Moreover, the reason of that log trace you are getting is yet unknown, but a clean test like the one I propose in my answer could help to debug it.

Comment: Thank you! After clean test like yours one and changing registry type from `mongodb` to `memory`, I found that problem was in `service` field, it contains upper case letters, but it seems that iota always saves `service` in lower case in registry. In `deviceRegistryMemory.js` file I come to `getByName` function and log length of `devices` variable, so I seen it's equal to zero. I tried to get devices from registry by different services names and discovered this. It seems that iota saves service name always in lower case.